# jQuery functions not working with ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using `ng-repeat` to repeat some `div` which show list of the records.

Issue: I want to do is that when user is clicked on the record popup should be open. `ng-repeat` is working perfectly but the issue is this that jQuery click event is not working for the element inside the `ng-repeat`.

**HTML code :**

```
<div data-ng-controller="AlbumCtrl">
  <div data-ng-repeat="z in songInfo">
    <div data-ng-repeat="b in z.tracks">
      <div class="border-bottom clearfix">
        <ul class="social-icon">
          <li class="share-popup"><a class="share-song-icon"></a>
            <ul class="popup">
              <li><a class="share-facebook">Facebook</a></li>
              <li class="last"><a class="save">Twitter</a></li>
              <div class="cancel"><a>Cancel</a></div>
            </ul>
          </li> 
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$('.share-popup').click(function(e) {  
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).children().toggleClass('active');
});
```

The jQuery click event working fine when I put div outside the `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `ng-repeat` renders all the div dynamically, and you are binding jQuery event at the start, at that time `share-popup` class element were not rendered on DOM, thats why those event don't get attached that element. You need to write your own custom directive that will restrict on class & while class element gets rendered on DOM this directive `link` function will get fired & event will get attached.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('sharePopup', function(){
    return{
       restrict: 'C',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs){
          element.on('click', function(e){
              e.stopPropagation();
              element.children().toggleClass('active');
          })
       }
    }
})
```

Better solution would be using `ng-class` inside your element, that would make more sense by doing code in more angular way. Then you don't need to write any external Javascript code that will handle on UI itself.

**Markup**

```html
<div class="border-bottom clearfix">
  <ul class="social-icon">
    <li class="share-popup" ng-click="b.active!=b.active; $event.stopPropagation();">
      <a class="share-song-icon" ng-class="{active: b.active}"></a>
      <ul class="popup">
        <li><a class="share-facebook">Facebook</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a class="save">Twitter</a></li>
        <div class="cancel"><a>Cancel</a></div>
      </ul>
    </li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome description..I hope it will going to work when implemented it in the application.Thanks

Comment: surely both the thing will work..second solution is more proper way..1st one is also cool way...

Comment: Yup..both are useful..once it will work for me..i will mark your answer.

Comment: for custom directive `sharePopup` i have to make `ng-model` for binding that directive with it or it will work for class as shown in my html code ?

Comment: @RohitJindal it will work for a class..no need of `ng-model` to run directive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79857/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-rohit-jindal).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are binding the event before the template was painted.

This is a common problem that everyone working on angular is facing. You should either use ng-click or if you want to use jQuery click then update your code with

```
$('.share-popup').on("click", function(e)
    {  
            e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).children().toggleClass('active');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When we use ng-repeat and need to trigger a jquery click event just try this it worked for me.

```
$(document).on("click", ".className", function() {

//your code here...

});
```